# Jquery to get all textarea elements with specific data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a a html with many textarea elements.

I need select all them, take your id  to use in a JQuery function and set a text editor.

Here is what I did, but I have no success with my JS.

HTML:

```
  <textarea id="editor1" name="namedit1"
        data-editor="ck">
    </textarea> 
    <textarea id="editor2" name="namedit2"
        data-editor="ck">
    </textarea> 
    ....
    <textarea id="editorN" name="nameditN"
        data-editor="ck">
    </textarea>
```

JS:

```
$("textarea").find(['data-editor="ck"']).each(
            function(){  
                    var input = $(this);
                    CKEDITOR.replace( input.id), {
                        uiColor: '#9AB8F3'
                    };
            });
```

Comment: Change your selector to `$("textarea[data-editor=ck]")`

Comment: sorry, I did but it doesnt work. I put  breakpoint in chrome devs into input var and it never is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find a text area element inside the text area.

Try with:

```
$('textarea[data-editor="ck"]').each(function(){  
                CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr('id')), {
                    uiColor: '#9AB8F3'
                };
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to `$("textarea[data-editor=ck]")` and make sure it's called on the page ready event.

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/52wb240h/

Comment: Thank you AndreFeijo. It works as well but the response of Andres Andrade is more complete.